# How get volume file system for the volume without assigned drive letter?

Tags: c++, winapi, storage

Usually to get volume file system we call [GetVolumeInformation win api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993(v=vs.85).aspx). But if i am tring to do this with volume without assigned drive letter, i got NOT_READY error, i think because GetVolumeInformation also returns volume lable which is not available in this case.
So how to get the file system  type for the volume without assigned drive letter?

---

[FSCTL_QUERY_FILE_SYSTEM_RECOGNITION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993(v=vs.85).aspx) Also can't do this with the same error. But widows discs manager show correct information about volumes... and it also is using apis.. but what apis?

Comment: What are you passing as the `lpRootPathName` parameter? I presume something like "\\?\Volume{...}\"? Some sample code would be handy.

Comment: yes, volume guid name and it is correct.

Comment: We have to take your word for that. If you showed some code we'd be able to double check.

Comment: It could be down to the exact syntax of the path, e.g., perhaps it only works if there is a backslash at the end, or only if there isn't.

Answer (score -1):

If drive letter is not assigned - volume is not mounted by any file system, as a result error NOT_READY is shown. Only way in this case read sectors on disk level and try recognize file-system by self, but of course this not real solution ) why drive letter is not assigned?

Comment: drive letter not assigned != volume yet not mounted. Volume can be mounted without assigning letters. Fo example you can do easyly so with vhdx files

Comment: widows discs manager show correct information about volumes including file system... and it also is using apis..